# Using new Gson().toJson(object) infinite loop

Tags: android, realm, gson

I have 2 tables using serial, **`Culinary`** and **`CulinaryMenu`** that extends **`RealmObject`** and Implements **`Serializable`**. `Culinary` ***hasMany*** `CulinaryMenu`, as showing in code below:

```
public class Culinary extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private RealmList<CulinaryMenu> menus;
}

public class CulinaryMenu extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}
```

I want to convert **`CulinaryMenu`** object to **`Gson string`** using code below, but didn't work. It will drain memory and not finishing (CulinaryMenu has 3 objects):

```
culinary = realm.where(Culinary.class).equalTo(AppConst.COLUMN_ID, 1).findFirst();
for (CulinaryMenu menu : culinary.getMenus()) {        
    System.out.println("CULINARY MENU: " + new Gson().toJson(menu));    
}
```

And if I state the object class I'm using, it return null:

```
culinary = realm.where(Culinary.class).equalTo(AppConst.COLUMN_ID, 1).findFirst();
for (CulinaryMenu menu : culinary.getMenus()) {        
    System.out.println("CULINARY MENU: " + new Gson().toJson(menu, CulinaryMenu.class));    
}
```

What's the problem? Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 3):

Solved. Must use realm.copyFromRealm(class). My working code:

```
culinary = realm.where(Culinary.class).equalTo(AppConst.COLUMN_ID, 1).findFirst();
List<CulinaryMenu> menus = realm.copyFromRealm(culinary.getMenus());
for (CulinaryMenu menu : menus) {        
    System.out.println("CULINARY MENU: " + new Gson().toJson(menu));    
}
```

I suspect the problem is when I just use **`culinary = realm.where()..`**, that return realm data object that still has realm relationship between models (Culinary has CulinaryMenu as children; CulinaryMenu has Culinary as parent. These data used by gson, resulting infinite loop). So we cut the realm 'things', and just use pure object with command: **`realm.copyFromRealm()`**.

Comment: Yep, recommended approach for sending managed objects through GSON is to detach them first

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
@Expose  private RealmList<CulinaryMenu> menus;

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```